# Importing blog articles from a WordPress site

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I am looking for a module to import any blog written on a WordPress site. Is there any module to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for periodic imports from a WP site to Drupal, then one module solution is the [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds). It allows you to do periodic imports of RSS feeds. You can point it at your WP **example.com/?feed=rss** RSS feed and have it import in your content.

Comment: Let me try this. Do i have to add something else ?. I have just added added feeds module and passed the url of wp feeds with 15 minute of interval.

Comment: Thanks shawn it works. But i found it here aggregator/sources/1 how can directly post from wordpress blog to drupal post with url something like blog/test

Comment: That is from the Drupal core **Aggregator** module. It is similar, but different from **Feeds**. Aggregator allows you to _display_ RSS sources on your site. Feeds _imports_ content into the Drupal CMS. Follow this [tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/feeds/) for a detailed walkthrough of importing content through Feeds.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [WordPress Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) is what you are looking for? Excerpt from its project page:

> supports migrating WordPress blog exports (WXR format) into Drupal using the [Migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate). Import of posts, pages, comments, attachments, tags and categories is supported. Imports can be rolled back completely.